# Unable to receive POSTMAN FORM-DATA in php

Tags: php, post, postman, form-data

I am trying to receive Data from POST Man using "FORM-DATA" but in PHP I am unable to get those value
My code is:

```
fwrite($Log,"Data: ".  print_r($_POST,TRUE));
$Data = $_POST['lattitude'];
fwrite($Log,"lat: $Data");
die($Data);
```

and I had also tried below code from stack overflow

```
fwrite($Log,"Data: ".  print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE));
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$lat = $data['lattitude'];
fwrite($Log,"lat: $Data");
die($Data);
```

any kind of help will be thankful !!

[image]

Comment: Try with: `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I need that data in FROM-DATA type not in any other format

Comment: same problem here